# Switching between GIT branches

Tags: git, branch

I changed the branch in GIT , which apparently had some errors .

Now i still get those errors even when I switched back to the previous branch which had absolutely no errors before. 
Is this some caching issue thats causing these problems ? 
Any clue why this is happening and how to get rid of these errors ?

Comment: did you get into a head-less state?

Comment: @dharag Can you give more information on the errors you are seeing? Cut and paste!

Comment: The errors are the application code error. Not anything related to GIT. I switched to this branch from IDE, ran the application, got errors , switched back to my previous branch , And now I still get these

Comment: git stash ; git checkout <good-branch> ; git clean -d -f;

Comment: It is called Git, not GIT.

Comment: Please paste the output of `git status` so we can see the state of your working tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your errors are continuing to reflect in a branch that was previously error-free, it is probable that your code (which has bugs) is untracked. Git allows you to switch between branches if your changes are untracked and not staged. You can solve this by stashing (git stash) your changes on your testing branch and then checking out (git checkout ) to your working branch to get back to a working version. If you think you want to regain access to the code that you stashed, you can pop it (git stash pop) back to your working tree. git stash basically pushes your temporary, non-commit ready code to a stack.